# Set background-image of body from controller

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3.1, view

I need assistance. I want to update the image URL in below CSS from the controller. I can use LESS and SCSS too. Is there a way?

```
.background{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: asset-url('ad-rose.jpg', image) no-repeat 0px 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help http://bonamin.org/blog/2012/03/08/dynamic-css-image-background-in-rails/

Comment: On doing so, it does not work.

%body.background{:style => "background: asset-url(\"#{@ad.to_s}\", image) no-repeat 0px 40px;)"}